# How can I make dual boot on Motorola Droid RAZR?

Tags: android, ubuntu-touch

I have Motorola Droid RAZR XT910 with Android 4.0.4 and I would like install Ubuntu Touch as second system. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

check this out

http://www.droidrzr.com/index.php/topic/11410-romdroid-razrany-kernel-ubuntu-touch-preview-
0301-alpha-update-2/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.